# Grouping & sorting results by date in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Suppose my users documents store the date they signed up, in the format of

```
date : {type:Date, default: Date.now}
```

So dates are stored like

```
Tue Jan 14 2014 23:34:02 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Say I want to get all users who signed up in January only. Is it possible with Mongoose by having  single date field (and if so, is it possible to sort them by, say, day), or should i create a day/month/year field in the Schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `Date` objects that span the month of January and then use them to filter on `date`:

```
Users.find({date: {$gte: new Date(2014, 0, 1), $lt: new Date(2014, 1, 1)}})
    .sort('date').exec(callback);
```